# Copy exchange 2013 rules using profman

Tags: outlook-redemption

I want to copy exiting profile rules and add them into new profile.
It is possible using the "profman.dll" ?

Answer (score 0):

Profman library allows manipulating MAPI profiles, but not rules.

You can find your client-defined rules listed as associated content (hidden) for the Inbox folder. Try using `MFCMAPI` for exploring Outlook internals.

Answer (score 0):

Not using Profman - the rules are stored in the Inbox and can be accessed using [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore).[Rules](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdorules.htm) collection. You can copy them one at a time adjusting the relevant folder entry ids as necessary.