# I want to copy exiting profile rules and add them into new profile. It is possible using the "redemption .dll"?

Tags: windows, dll, outlook, profile, rules

Can I use redemption.dll to copy the rules 
I want to copy exiting profile rules and add them to a new profile. It is possible to use the "redemption .dll"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Redemption is a wrapper around Extended MAPI which provides everything you are interested in. It is to you which wrapper to use.

Rules are stored as hidden items (associated content) on the Inbox folder of your account. I'd suggest using MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy for exploring Outlook internals and hidden properties.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered at [Copy exchange 2013 rules using profman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911959/copy-exchange-2013-rules-using-profman/61922823#61922823)

There is no reason to create multiple questions - better to create a single well formulated question with detailed questions and steps that you have already tried so far.